# UiWebView not working why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to open a url by using a uiwebview but when I run the simulator the I just see blank white screen and no webpage comes up why what am I doing wrong ?

h.file

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

m.file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

I followed the tutorials on net and try to find a solution but I was unable to find a way out.

Comment: try implementing UIWebView delegate methods to find if the webView is loading anything or not
- webViewDidFinishLoad:
- webView:didFailLoadWithError:

Answer (score 1):

You code is getting inside  `- webView:didFailLoadWithError:`

**Error**

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

To allow HTTP you need to add `App Transport Security Key` to your `plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

For more details check out the [configuring-app-transport-security](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Or you can test your WebView with

`@"https://google.com"`  instead of `@"http://google.com"`

Comment: *This only effects iOS9+ compiler

Comment: Also if I try to compile with iOS 7.1 still I got blank screen.

Comment: is your code going in any of the UIWebView delegates ?

Answer (score 0):

In info.Plist add this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Create one property in .h file
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *DisplaywebView;

In .m file

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.DisplaywebView  loadRequest:req];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instead of UIWebView refer WKWebView.

 WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc]
                                             init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@“http://google.com”];

WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame
                              configuration:configuration];
[webView setNavigationDelegate: self];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```